# Not able to connect to sandbox org through Force.com IDE and Data Loader - TLS protocol issue

Tags: data-loader, force.com-ide, tls

I am not able to connect to sandbox org through Force.com IDE and Data Loader.
It is giving error "TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to salesforce using https".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is because Salesforce has disabled TLS 1.0 encryption.

After June 25, 2016, at 9:30 AM PDT (16:30 UTC), all sandbox orgs -- whether existing, refreshed, or new -- will have TLS 1.0 automatically disabled and will require TLS 1.1 or later in HTTPS connections to or from the sandbox org.

For more information on Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0 refer - 
[https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207](http://Salesforce%20disabling%20TLS%201.0)

To fix this issue in Eclipse -

1) Update your eclipse.ini file to include this line:
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
You will find eclipse.ini file in eclipse installation directory.

2) If you are using Java 7, then you need to disable TLS1.0 and enable TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. (GO to control panel --> Java --> Advanced --> Advanced Security settings). TLS 1.0 is disabled by default in Java 8.

For Data Loader -

1)Uninstall older version of Data Loader and install Spring '16 version of Data Loader.

2) Install Java JRE 1.8.

Note:- Salesforce is going to disable TLS1.0 protocol on Production orgs in March 2017. So before salesforce disables TLS1.0, all the channels which are communicating to salesforce need to use TLS version 1.1 or higher.

Comment: I want to thank you and appreciate the time to detail the steps in this forum. Super helpful. I've spent half my day messing with this and super annoyed. This was the most helpful and detailed instructions out there so far. Others are super general and expect us all to know what they are talking about. Thanks again man, I have forwarded your instructions to others with screenshots so they don't fall into my trap of hours wasted today. Best, Louis M.

Comment: I made the changes suggested in the answer but when I try to create the project, it gives an error saying: Unable to fetch organization details for 'myuser@email.com' : TLSv1.1 I changed the ini file as well as the Java security settings have tls 1.1, 1.2 enabled. (Using Mac OS here)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rohit!

On a Mac, it is hard to find the Eclipse.ini file.  Here is what I found:

On a Mac OS X system, you can find eclipse.ini by right-clicking (or Ctrl+click) on the Eclipse executable in Finder, choose Show Package Contents, and then locate eclipse.ini in the Eclipse folder under Contents. The path is often

/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TLS 1.1 or greater!

I had same problem, I fixed it by changing my browser/windows TLS settings.

Please google : **`change TLS settings`** and follow instructions.

This SHOULD enable your Data Loader, atleast.

Hope it helps!